# Does every piece of gossip message carry a peer's x.509 certificate?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Hyperledger Fabric official documentation https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gossip.html#gossip-messaging mentioned that "Online peers indicate their availability by continually broadcasting “alive” messages, with each containing the public key infrastructure (PKI) ID and the signature of the sender over the message." I want to ask:

What does **"public key infrastructure (PKI) ID"** exactly mean here? Does it mean peer's x.509 certificate issued and signed by a CA? If yes, does it mean that every piece of gossip message carries a peer's x.509 certificate, right? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> What does "public key infrastructure (PKI) ID" exactly mean here? Does it mean peer's x.509 certificate issued and signed by a CA? If yes, does it mean that every piece of gossip message carries a peer's x.509 certificate, right? Thanks.

Public key infrastructure (PKI) ID is essentially a hashed value of x.509 certificate. So no, not every gossip messages carries x.509 cert.

Comment: OK, got it. So here Public key infrastructure (PKI) ID == peer's x.509 certificate's hashed value, right? And every gossip message carries x.509 certificate's hashed value, right?

Comment: Nope, not all gossip messages carries this information. Please take a look here for gossip messages: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/protos/gossip/message.proto